# Magento 2 Extension installation

Tags: php, extension-methods, magento2

When I install Search Autocomplete extension in magento 2(Version 2.2.2) through admin panel I got following issue

Step 1: Readiness Check (In This step following issue occured).

issue 1. Check Cron Scripts

issue 2. PHP Settings Check

issue 3. PHP Extensions Check

At the time of magento installation Readiness check was completed successfully but when I want to install any extension I got above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install extension through composer or
 directly put files in app -> code folder after that run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`